# How to Include SASS via the require element in an Aurelia template

Tags: webpack, sass, aurelia

I'm trying to get an Aurelia project to include a `.scss` file with a `<require>` tag in an html file as opposed to via an `import` statement in a typescript file.

I've looked at the [relevant Webpack issue](https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/issues/14), however I don't understand the suggested usage of `viewEngine.addResourcePlugin`.

Given a basic Aurelia+Webpack setup I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed loading required CSS file: app.scss
    at fixupCSSUrls (hmr-css-resource.js:32)
```

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const { AureliaPlugin } = require("aurelia-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "aurelia-bootstrapper",

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "[name].js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].js"
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
    modules: ["src", "node_modules"].map(x => path.resolve(x)),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      // Only apply style-loader when loading via import in a .ts file
      { test: /\.s?css$/i, issuer: { test: /\.[tj]s$/i }, use: ["style-loader"] },
      { test: /\.css$/i, use: ["css-loader"] },
      { test: /\.scss$/, use: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"] },
      { test: /\.ts$/i, use: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
      { test: /\.html$/i, use: "html-loader" },
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new AureliaPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

My app.html:

```
<template>
  <require from="./app.scss"></require>
  Hello World!
</template>
```

My main.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body aurelia-app="main">
    <script src="/dist/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My main.ts:

```
import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
         .standardConfiguration()
         .developmentLogging();
  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app')));
}
```

Comment: It should just work, your config looks like the bare minimum to make it work. I think maybe it's related to the code in your app.js/app.ts. May I see how you bootstrap it?

Comment: I added some more of my project skeleton. I also realized I was misapplying `style-loader` it should only be used when loading css/scss into typescript/javascript files, not into html. `import './app.scss'` works fine, <require from="./app.scss"></require> does not.

Comment: I have sass imports via require tag working in my Aurelia setup, I did not change anything to get it working as far as I'm aware of. I did run into an issue with jest mocks, here's a repo with a basic setup using it (including the jest mock fix) https://github.com/huochunpeng/demo-au-jest-scss

Comment: I just setup a new project using the cli, added a sass, import via require tag in app.html and it runs without any errors.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I'll have to try bootstrapping with the CLI and see how that differs from my manual setup.